# Difference between these two sentences

Tags: sentence-meaning, past-tense, translation

I was wondering if there's any actual difference between these two clauses:

> Mistakes that I did make so far

and

> Mistakes that I made so far

If I use Google Translate (yeah, I know that is an awful tool) on them, the translations are nearly the same. I speak Spanish BTW.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Mistakes that I did make so far" does not sound correct to me as a BrE speaker. This would only make sense if you were using "did" for emphasis:

> I rarely make mistakes, but of the mistakes that I *did* make so far [...]

Used by itself, the former sounds wrong, though, because "did" is superfluous. Use the latter.

Answer (score 2):

They have the same meaning, but have not been equivalent since about 1700 or so. In Modern English the version with *DO* is used in declarative contexts only to contrast with a prior negative:

> I did not make many mistakes, and the mistakes that I *did* make were minor.

Of course *DO* is required in non-declarative contexts:

> INTERROGATIVE: Did you make any mistakes?
>   NEGATIVE: I did not make many mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct. However, "did make" in the first one does the job of emphasizing the meaning. It makes more "impact."